# How to eliminate blank page at the end of printing the page using javascript print function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am printing the content using javascript print() function. Problem is all pages are correct but only last page of the print comes blank and of no use. So can you guide me how to eliminate that last page? below is the html Code. Please visit the below link and press Ctrl+P and save it to one note to see the output.
Note:- It only works fine with mozilla firefox
http://cromaplywood.com/NewBill.htm
Thanks in advance

Comment: Printing is a bit of an unstandardized nightmare, but I'd wager that getting rid of all that blank space at the top of your document might help.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the comment,
no I intentionally put that blank space at the top as page in which print comes will have some header printed already. Problem is that last page which comes blank and waste my one page for every print.

Comment: Ah okay. Well, I wish I had something more useful to say, but in my experience, browsers sorta do whatever they want when printing, and there's not a whole lot you can do about it. You could try reducing some of the paddings and margins throughout the page to guarantee that you don't even get close to spanning onto that third page, but beyond that, there's not a whole lot you can do. I haven't worked with jsPDF, but perhaps if you generated your reports with that library, you'd have more precise control over this sort of thing.